# Update/manipulate a PHP file with new code

Tags: php

I have a configuration file which, amongst other things, defines a whole bunch of values and callables. I'm writing a development tool which needs to update some of the definitions in this file. I can't think of a way to do this which isn't just reading the file and writing my string at a certain point defined by a comment within the file.

Imagine my file looks like this:

```
<?php

$things = [
    'a_thing' => 'some value',
    'callable_thing' => function() {
        return SomeClass();
    }
    // END THINGS
];
```

I'd like to insert a new array key into this array (the value of which might be any valid option), in alphabetical order. Is this possible, using Reflection maybe? Second best would be to place a specially formatted comment (i.e the "`// END THINGS`" comment) as a "target" and insert before it, but I can't help but feel that's pretty hacky, and doesn't satisfy the alphabetical requirement.

I'm aware of the implications of self-mutating code. This is a developer tool and would only be used locally to automate common file->create->update tasks when setting up new projects.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `var_export()` function to print the value of a variable in a way that can be evaluated. So you would load the file with `include($filename);`, and modify the contents of `$things`. Then you can update the file with:

```
$contents = '$things = ' . var_export($things, true) . ';';
file_put_contents($filename, $contents);
```

Comment: Thanks! Close, but I think it's a non-starter. I need to be able to maintain the code within the function closures. A quick test and it returns `Closure::__set_state(array())` for the `callable_thing`. I think I might need to do some nasty regex'ing to achieve this :(

Comment: I didn't even notice that you had a function in there. Could you take the functions out of the array, and define them as named functions, and then put function names in the array?

Comment: Sadly not. I went with using the comment "marker" and prepending the text before it. Doesn't tick all the boxes, but gets the job done.